No me aparece la carpeta de procedure en ninguna de las base de datos de SQL Server 2019
intente buscar la carpeta de "Procedure" en SQL Server 2019 y no me aparece, pero al crear la Procedure que en mi caso se llama "sp_RegistrarUsuario" si me aparece, ya que lo intente verificar con el siguiente código:
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE OBJECT_NAME (OBJECT_ID) = 'sp_RegistrarUsuario'

y me marco que existía.


Suena a un problema de permisos de tu usuario, revisa con el DBA para que te de mas permisos

que clase de permiso debo otorgarle a la DB para que me deje ver el archivo? disculpa, llevo poco trabajando con base de datos de esta forma.

Ya logre solucionarlo, creandolo directamente con click derecho en "Stored Procedures"
